# calling javascript from server side

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to call javascript function from server side

Comment: Please add some more detail to this question, I doubt whether it can be answered in this hazy state. Do you want to execute JavaScript code on server side? Or do you want to access a JavaScript function in the user's browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do a `Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>nameOfJavascriptFunction();</script>")`, or use [`ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx) with a similar script.

The effect is that you are outputting a script tag calling your function - the call is still done on the client side.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't you get this error trying that code? _Non-invocable member 'System.Web.HttpResponse.Output' cannot be used like a method._

Also, wouldn't we need to escape those double-quotes in the 'language' attribute?

Perhaps since you wrote this it has changed? This might be the way to go now:

_Response.Write("<script language=\"javascript\">nameOfJavascriptFunction();</script>");_

@Oded - I'll vote up for the right answer, I just wanted to make sure it is current.

Comment: @Dylan-INNOSoftware - Naw, you got it right... Thanks - good catch :)

Answer (score 0):

How about having the client side polling the server for actions instead? Do a call to the server side to check for a certain state, and if that state is fulfilled call the function? Should be easily achieved.